# D3.js How can I fix only the x-coordinate for all nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a visualization for a chrome extension. I'd like to fix the x-coordinate of my nodes, but leave the y-coordinate free. Is there any way to do that in D3?

This is in a force layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply set an `x` coordinate before you start the force layout and then don't change it in your `tick` function (i.e. the handler for the `tick` event).

Comment: The standard force layout tick function is: https://gist.github.com/zatricion/6122638

What I've done is set the tick function to go to ".xt" rather than ".x" like this: https://gist.github.com/zatricion/6122656
It works, but your way seems better.

If I naively do what you said, it doesn't work at all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: There's no "standard" way for the tick function, it depends what you're controlling with the tick layout. Could you give an example of what you're trying to do? It should work if (in the example you've linked to) you remove the lines that set `x1` and `x2` and replace `d.x` in the translate with whatever your desired translation is.

Comment: that won't work, I've tried it. I think creating a different key and value for the links and simply changing the x1, x2, and transform lines to use that attribute of d is the only way. This seems to be because the x1 variable is special in the force layout and needs to get updated on tick. If you can explain that, I'd accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `x1` shouldn't be set by the force layout. Also you don't need to update anything on tick, you could ignore the event entirely -- of course then nothing would happen.

Comment: sure x1 is an attribute of links, but I don't understand where your confusion lies. if x1 is not set, but y1 is, things happen, but not the things you want. so when I say "needs to get updated" I mean that in the context of my goal.

Comment: Wait, I thought you wanted static x coordinates? How does not updating `x1` makes things that you don't want happen?

Comment: I achieved my goal with the gist I posted. The problem with "not updating x1" is that you don't specify how to do that. If I just remove the lines that update x1, it causes the visualization to behave  oddly (everything goes to the left and the edges don't connect to the nodes). I don't know enough about d3 to elaborate.